# Deployment Failed BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-qnx

I am trying to run my Application from QNX Momentics and install it on my BlackBerry 10 Dev Alpha B device.

The following error occurs

> Deployment Failed: Info: Sending request: Install and Launch Info:
>   Action: Install and Launch Info: Debug native: on Info: File size:
>   954989 Info: Installing
>   com.example.projectname.testDev_tertimelinee81dc35f... Info:
>   Processing 954989 bytes actual_dname:: actual_id:: actual_version::
>   result::failure 881 debug token signature is not valid

When I am trying to run the app two options are appearing.
 1. Create debug token(fails)
 2. Import debug token(missing)

Any ideas how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're receiving indicates that you don't have a valid debug token installed on your device.

In Momentics go to `Preferences->BlackBerry->Signing` and check that your debug token has not expired and contains your device PIN. If it's not valid click `Create`, `Edit` or `Renew`.

Now click `Upload` to upload the debug token onto your device. Also make sure that your device has the correct date and time, this is a common gotcha when everything else looks normal.

You should now be able to deploy your app without receiving that error.